# Quartic From Gaussian Expectation

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, gaussian-process, kullback-leibler, weighted

$x$ is $d$-dimensional vector, Gaussian distributed with mean $\mu$ and covariance $\Sigma$. I want to simplify the same expression attached below but replacing $x$ with $x^2$ in the beginning of the expression s.t:
$$
E[x^2(x-m)^\intercal M(x-m)] 
$$

[image]

Thank you for any helpful tipp

Comment: By "$x^2$" would you mean the vector $(x_1^2,x_2^2,\ldots, x_d^2)$?

Comment: @whuber Yes sir